# How to write a vector or integer's coordinates in R's cpp11?

Tags: r, r-lib-cpp11

I am trying to add content to each of the coordinates of a vector `y1` from a vector `y2`. A reduced example is the following code but I don't understand why I must add `0 +` to the operation to make it work. Which is the logic behind it?

```
[[cpp11::register]] integers dummyexample(integers x1, integers x2) {
  int n = x1.size();
  writable::integers y1(n);
  writable::integers y2(n);

  // add content to y2
  // y2_1 = x2_1^2, y2_2 = x2_2^2, ...
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { y2[i] = pow(x2[i], 2); }

  // then

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’
    // y1[i] = y2[i];

    // this should resolve the ambiguity
    // y1.at(i) = y2.at(i);
    // not really, also error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’

    // maybe
    // y1.operator[](i).operator=(y2.operator[](i));

    // not either
    // int temp = y2[i];
    // y1[i] = temp;

    // 0 + y2_i works, but why?
    y1[i] = 0 + y2[i];
  }

  return y1;
}
```

Comment: and what is `nb2do`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot that in the minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y1[i]` and `y2[i]`, which are both elements of a writable integer vector, are of type `cpp11::writable::r_vector<int>::proxy`. It appears that the equals operator for this type has been defined in two places:

1. [r_vector.hpp](https://github.com/r-lib/cpp11/blob/500f642b4ea132ec8c168fc70a28e81e9510ece3/inst/include/cpp11/r_vector.hpp#L241) line 241: `proxy& operator=(const T& rhs);`
2. [integers.hpp](https://github.com/r-lib/cpp11/blob/500f642b4ea132ec8c168fc70a28e81e9510ece3/inst/include/cpp11/integers.hpp#L59) line 59: `inline typename r_vector<int>::proxy& r_vector<int>::proxy::operator=(const int& rhs)`.

The compiler does not know which definition to use, hence the error `ambiguous overload for 'operator='`.

The reason assigning `0 + y2[i]` works is that the compiler implicitly coerces this to an `int`, which it then knows how to assign as an element of a writable `integers` vector.

Instead of relying on implicit coercion, you could do explicitly [type cast](https://cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/) with either `(int) y2[i]` or `int (y2[i])`.

```cpp
#include "cpp11.hpp"
using namespace cpp11;

[[cpp11::register]] integers dummyexample(integers x1, integers x2)
{
    int n = x1.size();
    writable::integers y1(n);
    writable::integers y2(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        y2[i] = pow(x2[i], 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        y1[i] = int(y2[i]); // this is the only change
    }

    return y1;
}
```

This will compile and produce the expected result in R.

```r
dummyexample(c(2L, 3L), c(4L, 5L))
# [1] 16 25
```

I am not an expert in `cpp11` so I have been wondering whether this is a bug. I have come to the conclusion that it certainly feels like one. An alternative explanation is that this caused by importing more headers than required. If that is the case I would consider this an area where the documentation could be improved. In either case, I would consider reporting it as a GitHub issue.